# How to change last number in field to corresponding value as well?

Tags: mysql

Please find below a link to the table structure I have set up and to the query I am running.

```
CREATE TABLE phpbb_profile_fields_data
    (`user_id` int, `pf_firstname` varchar(50),
     `pf_lastname` varchar(100),`pf_workarea` varchar(255));

INSERT INTO phpbb_profile_fields_data
    (`user_id`, `pf_firstname`, `pf_lastname`, `pf_workarea`)
VALUES
    ('90', 'Piotr', 'Linski', '1;2;3;5;7;'),
    ('91', 'Monica', 'Reemers', '1;4;7;'),
    ('92', 'Lex', 'Zeewen', '2;3;'),
    ('93', 'Adele', 'Gerven', '7;')
;

SELECT d.pf_firstname, d.pf_lastname, d.pf_workarea,
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(d.pf_workarea, '7;', 'Friesland, ') , '5;', 'Flevoland, ') , '4;', 'Gelderland, ') , '3;', 'Brabant, ') , '2;', 'Limburg, ') , '1;', 'Landelijk, ') AS result
FROM phpbb_profile_fields_data d
ORDER BY d.pf_lastname ASC
```

[Here you can try it online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4a055/1)

If you run the query, you will see that for every row, the last number is, for some reason, not converted to the corresponding value.

- Why is this?
- And what modification is needed to get the last number replaced with the corresponding value as well?

Comment: Why don't you just use a table 'location' and do a join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you replace e.g. '7;' with 'Friesland, ', so of course the last element where no semicolon is there will not be replaced.

I do not think this is a clever approach anyway, because if you have to add another workplace, you have to change the query and not only the data. I would vote for generating a second table that maps numbers to workplaces. Then you can do a simple JOIN.

Comment: hi Koalo,

I agree with you that this is not a good solution. But I have to query three tables of which one can not be joined. So I am exploring if this replace option could do the trick for me.

Comment: I do not know your application, but if you really can not change your database layout, I would do this "manual JOIN" in your application code and not in SQL. Then you have other options, for example using an external JSON file and postprocessing your data. Still better than putting data into your SQL statement.

Comment: hi Koalo,

you are right, I am exploring to do it in php with something like:
$selected_opts = explode (";", $row['pf_workarea']);
and then do the changing of numbers in corresponding values.